# Why is the output returning this as not an integer, when the inputed value is, in fact, an integer?

Tags: python

So i'm new to python, but used to code in Lua a lot.
I'm having an issue with something basic that should be working but isn't.

```
def test():
    age = input("Enter Age:")

    if type(age) is int:
        print("Is integer.")
    else:
        print("Is not integer.")

test()
```

So basically, I run this, then I enter an integer, like "18".
The expected output would be "Is integer", but for some reason, it isn't; it's "Is not integer."

Answer (score 0):

In python every input is treated as string. If you want integers, you've to explicitly cast them like so

```
age = int(input("Enter Age:"))
```